# Read and print "STDIN and STDOUT"

Tags: python, arrays, list, stdout, stdin

[image]

I was doing a sample test on HackerRank, and although I knew how to code a solution to the problem, I didn't understand the stdin and stdout system.  My code didn't get the parameters and print nothing on stdout.

> Given a integer L and R (each one from a line on stdin) print on stdout the odd numbers(on an array) between them.

```
def oddNumbers (l, r): #this was already here
    l=int(input())
    r=int(input())
    list1=[]
    for i in range (l+1, r):
        if i%2 == 1:
            list1.append(i)
    print(list1)
    return

if__name'__main__': #this was already here
    # ...
```

[image]

Comment: l=int(input())
EOF when reading line

Comment: You are not supposed to read from STDIN. Hackerrank does that for you and then passes the variables `l` and `r` to function `oddNumbers`.

You just need to complete the function.

Comment: Thats the case on usual problems there but in this sample test it does need.

Comment: Can you post a link to the hacker rank question? Also, is there anything in the `if __name__` block?

Comment: Just did it. I think this "if__name__" has nothing to do with it. I am suposed to just code on the function

Comment: Whats the name of the problem? or a link to the question, not a picture of it. I've solved all of the python hackerrank questions and can help you a lot more if I know the specific question.

Comment: It it a sampe test that showed up because i'm going to do a company test..

Comment: here: https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/sample

Comment: They gave an example of it. I'm addin on the post.

Comment: You've shown two conflicting problem descriptions.

Comment: The image you just added is for a completely different problem, it's adding multiple lines of numbers.

Comment: I know. It was written: "Click here to know more about handling STDIN and STDOUT in Python3." and it showed me this

Comment: SOLVED! TY all guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to read the input or print the results yourself. The instructions say

> Locked stub code in the editor reads the following input from stdin and **passes it to the function**

and

> The function must **return** an array of integers...

So get rid of the `int(input())` lines, and change `print(list1)` to `return list1`.

I don't see where you got the instructions you quoted at the top, they're not in the image of the site at the bottom.